# single click listener for different text view android

Tags: android

I have implemented single click listener for different text view in sherlock fragment
Here is my code

```
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_plan).setOnClickListener(btn1Listener);
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_plan1).setOnClickListener(btn1Listener);
```

and my listener code

```
   private View.OnClickListener btn1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            String title=null;
            String tag=null;
               switch(v.getId())
              {
                case R.id.tv_plan:
                      System.out.println("Plan ids"  +v.getId());
                    title= "My Plan"; tag = "viewplan_dialog";
                    Utilsdialog dialog_vwplan = new Utilsdialog(context, R.layout.child,title, tag);
                    System.out.println("Before showing dialog tag");
                    dialog_vwplan.show(fm, tag);
                    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                     break;
                case R.id.tv_plan1:
                    System.out.println("Plan ids"  +v.getId());
                    title= "Change plan"; tag = "changeplan_dialog";
                    Utilsdialog dialog_chgplan = new Utilsdialog(context, R.layout.child,title, tag);
                    dialog_chgplan.show(fm, tag);
                     break;

                 }
      }

  };
```

My code always calls the last specified listener that is the **tv_plan1** listener but i need to provide onclick listener for both text views. My current code call tv_plan1 for both text view clicks....pls help

Comment: can you post the code for creating textviews

Comment: use this  implements
  OnClickListener in your class

Comment: can we specify same value for onclick attributes of text view in xml.....

Answer (score 2):

try this, use `Button` instead of `TextView`.

First implements your activity `OnClickListener`.

```
 public class Auctions extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   private Button menu_Btn;
private Button deal_Btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.xml);
            menu_Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    deal_Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deals);
}  
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

     case R.id.menu:{
                  System.out.println("Plan ids"  +v.getId());
                title= "My Plan"; tag = "viewplan_dialog";
                Utilsdialog dialog_vwplan = new Utilsdialog(context, R.layout.child,title, tag);
                System.out.println("Before showing dialog tag");
                dialog_vwplan.show(fm, tag);
                System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                 break;
     }
            case R.id.deals:{
                System.out.println("Plan ids"  +v.getId());
                title= "Change plan"; tag = "changeplan_dialog";
                Utilsdialog dialog_chgplan = new Utilsdialog(context, R.layout.child,title, tag);
                dialog_chgplan.show(fm, tag);
                 break;
       }


    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Implements ur activity to onclicklistner and unimplemented it will add `onClick(View v)`.handle your click in ur method

Comment: friend i think my problem is not in onclick ....visit tis question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641910/text-view-conflicting-android

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this?

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="test"
    android:text="Datepicker"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="test"
    android:text="Test 2"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick)

Then in your activity:

```
public void test(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: friend i think my problem is not in onclick ....visit tis question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641910/text-view-conflicting-android