# text view conflicting android

Tags: android

MY layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="3"
 >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo_user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/user_pic"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_descrip"
    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text_user"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/photo_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/user_info"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#AA000000"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="7"
  android:background="#000000"
   >
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >
   <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/plan_text0"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_viewplan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/plan_text"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_plan1"
        android:paddingLeft="215dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/plan_text1"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
<View
    android:id="@+id/place_view1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="2dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
   android:background="#5C5C5C"
    />
 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/place_view1"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >
   <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/services_text0"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_service"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/services_text"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_service1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_plan1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="215dp"
        android:text="@string/services_text1"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
   <View
   android:id="@+id/place_view2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="2dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
   android:background="#5C5C5C"
    />
   <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/place_view2"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >
   <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/bill_text0"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_bill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bill_text"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_bill1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_service1"
        android:paddingLeft="215dp"
         android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bill_text1"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
 <View
   android:id="@+id/place_view3"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="2dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
   android:background="#5C5C5C"
    />
   <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/place_view3"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >
   <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/request_text0"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_request"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/request_text"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_request1"
        android:paddingLeft="215dp"
         android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/request_text1"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <View
   android:id="@+id/place_view4"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="2dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    />
  <RelativeLayout 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/place_view4"
      >
      <ExpandableListView 
          android:id="@+id/ex_notifi"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          ></ExpandableListView>

  </RelativeLayout>



   </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in my sherlock fragment class i have same listener for all text views

```
      getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_viewplan).setOnClickListener(this);
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_plan1).setOnClickListener(this);
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_service).setOnClickListener(this);
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_service1).setOnClickListener(this);
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_bill).setOnClickListener(this);
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_bill1).setOnClickListener(this);
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_request).setOnClickListener(this);
  getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_request1).setOnClickListener(this);
```

in my onclick listener

```
   switch(v.getId())
  {
    case R.id.tv_viewplan:
        System.out.println("Plan ids"  +v.getId());
        title= "My Plan"; tag = "viewplan_dialog";
        Utilsdialog dialog_vwplan = new Utilsdialog(context, R.layout.child, title, tag);
        dialog_vwplan.show(fm, tag);
         break;
    case R.id.tv_plan1:
     System.out.println("Plan ids"  +v.getId());
        title= "Change plan"; tag = "changeplan_dialog";
        Utilsdialog dialog_chgplan = new Utilsdialog(context, R.layout.child,title, tag);
        dialog_chgplan.show(fm, tag);
         break;
    case R.id.tv_service:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECTED VIEW SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         break;

    case R.id.tv_service1:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECTED ADD SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         break;
    case R.id.tv_request:

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECTED TRACK REQUEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         break;
    case R.id.tv_request1:

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECTED ADD REQUEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         break;
    case R.id.tv_bill:

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECTED VIEW BILL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         break;
    case R.id.tv_bill1:

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECTED PAY BILL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         break;

     }
```

The problem is for tv_viewplan and tv_plan same id is generated and also for tv_service and tv_servive1 has same ids. so switch calls incorrect block.  I donno how is this possible....pls help

Answer (score 0):

different view with different id name cant have same id at time. Never and ever. check out you have different id name for each view. There is alternative method checking tag for each view where you should assign unique tag for each view. but logically first one should work.

Comment: yeah i have checked R.java but in the switch block above both tv_viewplan and tv_plan1 having same view id. for both the case the tv_plan1 case gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to clean the project. 
If you are using eclipse then open your Project option in Menu , please find clean option in Submenu of Project.
Select your project and click ok button  in popupwindow.
If you do like this then you can get new id's to your project. 
If you have any issues after clean the project let me know.
```

Comment: yeah i have cleaned my project many times. In r.java the views have different id value. but when switch block executed both views have  same view id.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Rebuild your project and make sure no duplicate ids on each textview

if didn't work, try to do this

why won't you just remove all
     `getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_viewplan).setOnClickListener(this);`

and add 
     `android:onclick="clickText"`
in every textView that are clickable

then add this function

```
 public void clickText(View v){
 //put your switch case here...
 }
```

Comment: i can't seem to identify what could have caused the problem coz i think your code is fine. try to restart eclipse then.

Comment: by the way, can you check how many times the the switch case have been called?

Comment: can you post system.out. result from your console, the one you printed inside the case
the actual result after you ran it

Comment: for "tv_viewplan" System.out(836): Plan ids2130968618  and for "tv_plan1" System.out(836): Plan ids2130968618

Comment: there shoud be two system.out right? coz you said there are two similar ids?

Comment: when i click text view tv_plan1 and tv_viewplan both executes the same tv_viewplan case code..tv_viewplan is not executing the case R.id.tv_viewplan instead R.id.tv_plan1. u got it ah...

Comment: hmmm that's weird can you just try to change the ids? for each?

Comment: yeah i found the problem is in layout file. I have used android:attribute padding left.thank you ...